# FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword return null user

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am developing on the flutter platform and using FirebaseAuth library for dart.

When I call [FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signInWithEmailAndPassword.html), the user returned in the AuthResult is null.

The problem is that no error was thrown. So I am really confused. According to the docs, there is a list of error code that can be thrown. But in this instance it is just silently failing. Does anyone know why it could be silently failing without communicating any sort of error back?

My code looks as follows...

```
try {
  final AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email:email, 
    password:password
  );
  final FirebaseUser user = result.user;

  if (user != null) {
    callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Fail);
    return;
  }

  _user = user;
  callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Success);
}
catch (e) {
  print("CODE:"+e.code+'\n');
  print("MESSAGE:"+e.message+'\n');
  callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Success);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't invert the `if` condition? You're now returning `Success` when the user is `null`, and `Fail` when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have reversed your conditions when checking for the presence of a user in the AuthResult response. But you could also simplify your code like this:

```
try {
  FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email:email,
    password:password
  ).then((authResult){
    if(authResult.user != null){
      _user = authResult.user;
      callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Success);
    }else{
      callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Fail);
    }
  });
} catch (e) {
  print("CODE:"+e.code+'\n');
  print("MESSAGE:"+e.message+'\n');
  callback(RequestUserSignInResult.Fail);
}
```